# IAM policy condition that request for key with any value

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have a working IAM policy that allow users to create EBS devices only if given tags are there, now it has set of predefined input list but my requirement is that I want to check for key, not for value, so the question is: can we have a key with any user input value that we can accept?

If the tag key is used like `"aws:RequestTag/Environment": ["dev", "stage", "prod"]` then it works, but I need a solution where I can pass any value at the time of EBS creation, and that should be accepted by the IAM policy.

```
"Condition": {
    "StringEquals": {
        "aws:RequestTag/owner": ["*"],
        "aws:RequestTag/Environment": ["dev", "stage", "prod" ]
    },
    "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
        "aws:TagKeys": ["Environment]
    },
    "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
        "aws:TagKeys": ["owner"]
    }
}
```

How we can give accept any value for given key?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking, because your policy already appears to do what you appear to be asking: require a specific tag in the request regardless of value.  `"StringEquals": { "aws:RequestTag/owner": ["*"] }` should require the 'owner' tag to be present, regardless of value.  If this isn't what you are looking for, please clarify.

Comment: Yes that’s exactly what I’m up to .. but this policy is not working “*” is getting considered as a string input and this policy works if I input “*” as owner tags value

Comment: Actually, my previous comment was incorrect. 
 `StringEquals` is an equality comparison. I believe  `StringLike` is what you are actually looking for, so that `*` is interpreted as a wildcard.

Comment: Thanks that solved the one problem of accepting any value but it also works when no value is given to a tag

Comment: Use `StringLike` with `"?*"`  That would require a non-empty value because `?` matches exactly 1 character and `*` matches 0 or more characters

Answer (score 1):

A tag with any value = deny the request without this tag.

So you can just add another statement to deny the request if the tag does not exist.

A [Null condition operator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition_operators.html#Conditions_Null) checks if a condition key is present at the time of authorization. The key inside the Null condition can take either true or false as its value:

1. True: the key doesn't exist, so the expression evaluates to null and the  condition returns true.
2. False: the key exists, and its value is not null. The condition fails.

So you need three statements to implement this logic:

- Allow the action explicitly.
- Deny the action if the tag is missing.
- Deny the action if the tag is empty.

```
{
   "Sid": "AllowTheActionHere",
   ...
},
{
    "Sid": "EnforceOwnerTag",
    ...
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Condition": {
        "Null": {"aws:RequestTag/owner": "true"}
    }
},
{
    "Sid": "PreventEmptyOwnerTag",
    ...
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
            "aws:RequestTag/owner": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works well even when it has no value which can't be allowed but if used "false" and  the key has some value then the condition fails and does not allow to create a resource.

Comment: You should then add another deny statement to prevent empty tags. See the update above.